# Statements In Hindu Texts Of Deliberately Mistaken Info

Tags: tantra, maya, truth

There are many places in Tantra excerpts I’ve read, Arthur Avalon and such, where Shiva tells Parvati that there is deliberate misleading info in Hindu texts. He says that stuff is put in there to throw people off, influences them to make mistakes, stay trapped in maya, illusion. Similar kinds of stuff is stated in different Puran and ancillary religious texts of Hinduism.

It seems really obvious when you read certain things, that this is correct. So then how do you know what to rely on or what to disregard, exactly ? Is the solution to this stated anywhere ? How do you know what to trust in Hinduism ?

Comment: Scriptures hide many things it's true .. the most important things they will never tell .. the best way is to learn from the Guru. Gradually as one's Sadhana evolves one can also differentiate between falsehood and truth.

Comment: Thx so much @Rickross  I agree 100% 

Comment: @devibhakt It is also about adhikara.Not every Tom Dick Harry has the right to read scriptures.First one has to do chitta-shuddhi using sadhanas as directed by the Guru i.e purify one self and follow strict discipline to be qualified to read a scripture.To prevent the unworthy/unfit from gaining wrong knowledge/misinterpretation scripture protects itself by mentioning things that don't make any direct sense so that they repeatedly make mistakes and eventually give up.I know many ppl who did various mantra-sadhanas/homas for 10-15 years before they were allowed to touch any major scripture....

Comment: So as to which scripture to trust, ones which our Acharyas reference/have written commentaries upon can be one indication....

Comment: @Rāmachandra Thx, yes, that makes sense 